# Floating div positioning

Tags: css, html

I need a floating rectangle (100% width, 100px height) to appear exactly 20px above the bottom of a page. How can I do that?

The code below shows the rectangle at the bottom of the browser window not the page - so if the page is taller than what can fit in the screen, the rectangle appears somewhere in the middle of the page.

```
<div style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: 20px; background-color: #000000; width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 0px; color: white; ">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the element that contains it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to the rectangle div's parent.  This will position the div 20px from the bottom of the parent element.

Answer (score 17):

- As suggested by @Laxman13, you need to add `position: relative` to the parent of the "floating rectangle". The relevant parent in this case just happens to be the `body` element.
- [Read this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) / [this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) / [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) to help understand the `position` property.

```css
body {
  position: relative
}

#floatingRectangle {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="floatingRectangle">
  <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />Long content<br />
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/mvCUH/)

Comment: On second thought, are you sure that you're not just after a Sticky Footer? See: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: **NOTE:** this answer changed the floating div from `position: absolute;` in the original question to `position: fixed;`. Depending on what you are going for, that makes a difference. In my case, only `absolute` scrolled correctly. -- If one doesn't work for you, try the other. See also the set of links about `position` given above.